# How to disable azure python function read-only

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I have created an azure functions timer trigger app by python and deploy it.
But console outputs read-only file systems error.

`Exception while executing function: <Function> <--- Result: Failure Exception: OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'output.json' Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 312, in _handle__invocation_request self.__run_sync_func, invocation_id, fi.func, args) File`

I have seen it and deploy with nozip, but Linux App can't edit at App Service Editor.
[How to disable Read Only mode in Azure Function App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53630773/how-to-disable-read-only-mode-in-azure-function-app)

Can anyone fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, since azure function(python) run on linux, so "App Service Editor" is not available to us. And we can not edit the function on azure portal. What we can do is edit it on VS code and then deploy it to azure. (If you just want to edit "Application settings" or "Connection strings", you can edit them by clicking "Configuration" under "Overview" on portal).