# The file cannot be copied onto itself from Azure Function Console

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have created an Azure Function (Windows - Consumption Plan). I need to copy a `dylib` file into the function apps `bin` folder.

I get a message stating `The file cannot be copied onto itself.`. How can I solve this ?

```
C:\home\site\wwwroot>copy libwkhtmltox.dylib /bin/libwkhtmltox.dylib
The file cannot be copied onto itself.
        0 file(s) copied.
```

[image]

Note: I have published this app to Azure from VS studio.

**UPDATE - AFTER REMOVING** `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE`
[image]

[image]

Comment: Delete the `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` configuration, or modify it to 0 and they try copying!

Comment: I am getting the same result. Further, the warning `Your app is currently in read only mode because you are running from a package file. To make any changes, please update the content in your zip file and WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE app setting.` Still appears.

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT Further, I have published this app to Azure from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

> I get a message stating `The file cannot be copied onto itself.`
>
> the warning `Your app is currently in read only mode because you are running from a package file. To make any changes, please update the content in your zip file and WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE app setting.`
> Still appears

For the above error
I tried to deploy one function app from my VS CODE to Azure and after that i have got the similar  issue if i am trying to copy files inside kudu console.

[image]

As per @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT suggestion , I deleted the `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE`  from **configuration** setting and then **save** and **refresh** and then go to **Advance Tools** . And run the `cmd` as below screenshot .

[image]

And it works fine here are some screenshot for reference :

[image]

Comment: For me its different. When I remove `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE ` the entire content in the `wwwroot` folder gets erased except for  host.json.

Comment: "Your app is currently in read only mode because you are running from a package file. To make any changes, please update the content in your zip file and `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` app setting"

Is that error appears after remove above configuration .

Comment: The error goes away, however the content of `wwwroot` also goes away. See update post I have included screenshots.

Comment: Thanks @Illep , Could you please refer this SO THREAD: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53630773/how-to-disable-read-only-mode-in-azure-function-app